# Remainder of trick-number divided by 9

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

How can I calculate the remainder of something like $199\cdot 741934^{1234}$ by 9?

Answer (score 1):

Using modulo arithmetic (mod 9):

$$199 \cdot 741934^{1234} \equiv 1 \cdot 1^{1234} \equiv 1$$

So the above number yields a remainder of 1 when divided by 9.

[We can use the trick of summing up the digits to find out that $199 \equiv 1$ (mod 9). Namely, 1+9+9 = 19, which has a remainder of 1 when divided by 9.

Can do the same for 741934.]

Comment: Hi - ok thats cool :) And what If I have $199 \cdot 741937^{1234}$, since then the second number has sum of digits 31 ?

Comment: Same idea, Vazrael. Since 31 divided by 9 yields a remainder of 4, we have $741937 \equiv 4$ (mod 9).

Comment: Now $4^{1234}$ is a bit trickier to deal with. But I observe that $4^3 = 64 \equiv 1$ (mod 9), so $4^{1234} = (4^3)^{411} \cdot 4 \equiv \dots$ Can you take it from here?